# As a newcomer, I had to use Google to learn how to use the editor. Can this be improved?

Tags: discussion, markdown, user-interface, editor

As a new user, I found the editor unintuitive. There are too many popups with hidden information. I Googled and got the answers I needed from another thread here on Stack Overflow.

I personally find that the choices, dropdowns, and design of eg. the editor from Wikipedia is far more user friendly than the one here. Maybe some of the ideas from Wikipedia or other sites or programs like Word can be borrowed to make the editor easier to use.

Not all of us are superusers familiar with Markdown and Markdown editors. Can we improve the user friendliness of the editor, especially for new users?

Comment: This is not very helpful in its current form. It says little more than "the editor is not very intuitive and it should be different". Can you specify what features you had trouble with exactly? How exactly would you rethink the editor, what would that entail?

Comment: You didn't see the ? icon at the top right of the editor screen?

Comment: Or you did see it and it didn't help?

Comment: @Pekka. No, what I ment was that my initial experience as a newcommer is not that great. - This must be an issue in itself. And I dont have a solution for it. 
Next, as I wrote, older questions are making suggestions to new features. Why not take a look at it?

Comment: @RobertLongson As a newcommer I saw a lot of stuff. But my goal wasnt to look for icons or waste my time looking for answers. I just wanted to post my question and make it look good for readability.

Comment: @topic I just want to ask the question - Can the editor be better/ more intuitive?

Comment: There's thousands of suggestions for new features on Meta. They're not all guaranteed to improve the experience... `This must be an issue in itself.` sort of, but in a very broad, general way that's not really going to change anything. I could write a letter to Microsoft telling them "I found Windows not very intuitive" and it would to be thrown into a bin right away because there's nothing in it that they could even forward to anyone who collects user feedback. To convert this into something productive, it would be helpful if you could actually describe what exactly didn't work for you.

Comment: How would you suggest that it be made better/more intuitive. Just saying "rethink the editor" isn't a useful proposal.

Comment: @toLucky sure, something can always be made more intuitive, but the problem is how.  What is unintuitive to you may be intuitive to someone else.  That's why Pekka and Robert were asking for specific items that you feel needed improvement.  They're trying to help you proposal to give the designers and developers of the site soemthing to focus on

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ok, I'll try.

My question was about Audio within Xamarin+Visual Studio with code in C#

So. the writing of the question was easy. But for readability, I had to google "Markdown StackOverflow C#" and I found out, that I had to use <!-- language: c# --> followed by my code. Then I had to mark the code and click the {} icon or use Ctrl+k

Its all fine, now that I know it, but why couldnt something this simple be more intuitive?
Idea - Some dropdown saying "Markdown" and you then select the language of your code.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree, design is a B...H. But if Apple can get it right. So can StackOverflow. Iterations and failing, I get that and I support that. But hiding behind "Well the next guy just wont like what we change it into" is giving up. - I can't support that

Comment: There is help when you look [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Imo, he tries to make his question readable. For a 1rst question I find the format really good. He didn't see the `help` button and didn't click on `Learn more...` where he could have find all the information needed. But he tries! When was the last time you saw 1rep user making readable post?

Comment: I've edited this to sound less accusatory and more constructive. After a re-read, I think there *is* a good point buried in here, but it still needs more clarification about what *exactly* was difficult, and what *exactly* would be more intuitive.

Comment: @davidism, From the comment the main issue seems to be the "Markdown ". You have to click `Help` then `Learn More` Scroll to :Syntax highlighting for code . Copy past `<!-- language: lang-js -->` into your code. And if you are looking for a specific language. You have to travel back to help page. and click the `will be inferred from the question's tags.` link. To find the correct language. That's a lot.

Comment: a bit over 6 to 8 months ago the team ventured into gathering requirements for a new Ask page. You can find that question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page). Is there anything in the ideas there that would have helped you in the first usage of the editor?

Comment: @toLucky: "*Then I had to mark the code and click the {} icon or use Ctrl+k Its all fine, now that I know it, but why couldnt something this simple be more intuitive?*" And how is that any less intuitive than picking the code formatting icon in the Wikipedia editor? "*I had to use <!-- language: c# --> followed by my code.*" No, you did not. That's only for syntax highlighting, and even then, if you use the C# tag, it will default to C# highlighting for code blocks. Personally, I've never had to use the explicit highlighting in my many years on SO.

Comment: I sincerely hope you become a successful software developer with a very large customer base, and I hope every single one of them file issues with your software in the incomprehensible manner you did here.  And I hope, once you have spent twenty years struggling to get any details out of them (like, collectively, everybody here has done), I hope you look back on this comment and weep.  Weep tears of regret and shame.

Comment: Seriously? You were in such a rush to post your question that you couldn't be bothered to click the question mark icon that is commonly associated with help? I've never had a problem with the editor that I couldn't solve by reading the relevant help text.

Comment: @TinyGiant [except that time when you couldn't figure out why it required you an extra space between brackets to make your text linkify.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260455/formatting-issues-when-using-tagsyntax-along-with-a-link-in-the-editor) I had to read Commonmark spec to figure out what I was doing wrong, just to be told that I'm doing nothing wrong.

Comment: @Braiam yes that is a bit unintuitive, but reading the question I had already assumed the answer before even seeing the answer, so I would probably not have had an _extended_ issue in that situation. Regardless, that isn't something that new users are likely to be doing anyways.

Comment: @TinyGiant and Will. In my oppinion a simple click on downarrow would have shows just as much, but without ncegative wibe. - Everyone else, read my comment to JasonC's answer further down.

Comment: @toLucky *"...or waste my time looking for answers."* - As an aside, consider two things here: It is often *not* a waste of your time to look for answers, which is generally quicker than typing an actual question. More importantly, in *this* community, you spending your time looking for answers so *others* don't waste their time is one of our primary values, and you *are* expected to do that. If that doesn't work for you that's *totally OK*, but it won't be well-received *here*. :) Check out [this classic](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), linked from [ask].

Comment: The OP now seems to be able to identify the specific issue that they had: [*"I did not see the ?-icon. I did not see it, I did not expect it."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345924/as-a-newcomer-i-had-to-use-google-to-learn-how-to-use-the-editor-can-this-be-i/345956?noredirect=1#comment459620_345956). @toLucky Consider editing your post to be clear on this, up to this point it wasn't apparent what problem you ran in to.

Comment: *"my goal wasnt to look for icons or waste my time looking for answers."* i'd be weary of that last part where your implying it's a waste of your time looking for answers

Answer (score 9):

To be honest it is very difficult for me to wrap my head around the issues that you were having.

The thing is:

> Not all of us are superusers familiar with Markdown and Markdown editors

It is not clear to me why one needs to be familiar with Markdown to use the editor, as the editor uses a small set of extremely standard icons, provides the expected functionality that most WYSIWYG editors have, and has the usual behavior of applying changes to highlighted text (if text is highlighted). So given that an understanding of Markdown is not required to use the rather run-of-the-mill editor, the premise here seems a bit odd to me.

The editor itself:

- Uses standard, recognizable icons for all actions (big quotes for quotes, bulleted and numbered list icons for lists, formatting icons, chain link for links, brackets for code, etc.)
- Supports the rather standard flow of applying the tool button you press to the text you have highlighted (or setting you up to type if you have no text highlighted).
- Provides tooltips on every icon if you do not know what they mean.
- Provides pretty much the same basic functionality that every other WYSIWYG editor provides.
- Has a help button on it.
- Is based on Markdown which you *may* not be familiar with, this I could understand, although all the documentation for it *is* there, and it is fairly straightforward in that raw Markdown is still [readily readable as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/9c448546-bf4d-44b0-8130-bb0670c593fa/view-source) - IMHO Markdown is a *very* intuitive choice as it mostly mirrors what you'd type anyways in a plain-text environment. And, like I mentioned above, it should be moot: You don't actually need to know Markdown to use the editor.
- Has a *live* preview directly underneath it, so if you're more into experimenting, you can get feedback on your results immediately.
- Also, as a side note: Syntax highlighting will be done automatically based on the language tag you choose. There is generally no need to specify a language manually or take any other action here.
- Additionally, the editor even supports some basic HTML, if you're more familiar with that.

I wanted to make a little GIF showing the tooltips but, sadly, the tooltips aren't captured by my screen recording tool, so just pretend they're there in the beginning. The help is also there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I am having a hard time imagining what you found on Google that wasn't already directly linked to from the editor with the exception of [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), which I don't believe has a direct path.

I'm not saying that you're "wrong" in finding it nonintuitive, but I (and I presume many others here) am having trouble understanding *why*, as there is nothing particularly out of the ordinary or quirky about this editor compared to every other editor, and all of the help is there on the editor. I can't actually think of any way this could be more streamlined.

So perhaps you could come up with a more specific list of exactly what problems you had and form those into feature requests, noting that many feature requests already exist and so you should do a bit of searching first.

In any case if you're troubled by the editor just give it your best shot. You might get a slight scoff in comments but for the most part it'll be fine, and it won't be long before you pick it up.

---

By the way, in the spirit of animated GIFs, here is how the current editor works, which seems to address all of the issues...

- Highlight code and press appropriate button - Traditional interface, consistent with text editors in general, requires no markdown knowledge.
- Code highlighting is determined automatically (by tag, but you don't need to think about it at all; write code, tag like you'd tag anyways, observe resulting magic).
- Live preview shows what is happening.
- Other questions searched as you type, so you don't have to spend additional time searching.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I am not sure how it could be made more smooth, although based on your comments below perhaps the help button could be animated the first time you use the editor to draw attention to it, if you need it. This could be a good candidate for a feature request should you choose to write a clear one (search first, it may exist).

Comment: I think, that there is a great idea hidden in your answer here - The illustrative gif.  Even though it doesnt show tooltips, I think that it would have given me some of the answers that I needed writing my first question. My suggestion is: Make the first badge watching an introduction/tutorial video of the editor. Reading up on some of the older posts by @Pekka and others. I think this could be the answer to a lot of ideas. Eg. Showing examples of what is good and bad questions, titles and so on.

Comment: @toLucky I will admit I have the same problem wrapping my head around the usefulness of this GIF as documentation as I do trying to understand your original difficulties: The GIF merely shows a user looking at tooltips and clicking the help button, but these are things that I feel you should just... do. It is a strange day indeed when documentation is expected to contain an animation of "how to click a help button". Could you clarify your issue? Is the issue that the help button wasn't obvious? Are you not used to tooltips? Were the toolbar not recognizable? What happened? This info will help.

Comment: @toLucky  (It almost feels like adding "How to use a keyboard and mouse" to the documentation! :) ) And also this begs the question: If a user was not naturally inclined to do the things that this GIF shows (see icons / click help / look at tool tips / etc.), would they be inclined to take a tour / visit the page that had this GIF? Please note I am not writing any of this in any sort of critical tone, I am just genuinely unclear on what the original barrier was for you. :)

Comment: Try starting here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_intelligence_(psychology)) - We see and learn diffrently. I learn best through visually seeing how an issue is handled not reading about it. I think that it was @Pekka on this page: [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) descriped how examples could help getting familiar with the editor-features.

Comment: Jason C, I dont think I can get it much closer. I did not see the ?-icon. I did not see it, I did not expect it. I googled. - I did not expect the editor to be the cause of time-waste. I expected it to help in an intuitive way. - Thats all

Comment: @toLucky What if the help button (the little question mark) had bounced up and down on your first visit to the page and/or what if it were black (or another color) instead of gray?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like all recommendations in the post are already implemented:

- ui for the editor includes toolbar similar to Word as suggested which as well provides link to help on the right side (where help menu is often present)
- asking basic question requires no additional knowledge that is not available in direct help: writing text does not require any extra knowledge except breaking wall of text into paragraphs; lists/bullet points are  directly available on the toolbar, writing code in other language than JS/CSS/HTML needs one click on help icon and reading "code" topic.
- even if you know absolutely nothing about formatting asking question without any formatting would be fine - post will not be downvoted for mis-formatted (lack of 4 spaces) code sample or sample with wrong language highlighting. Post will be edited quickly to look fine. (It does not mean one no longer need to format code, just users with low reputation are expected to not know *some* rules)

Comment: Hi Alexei - a first-time-writer should know this how? - Here are the  thourght going through my head as I was writing for the first time. 
1) How to ask my question in a way that everyone understands. 2) pick a good title .... Struggling with the editor was far from one of the items on that list. In a perfect world the editor shouldn't be. Perfect, is a rare thing, but I didn't expect the editor to cause the amount of time-loss that I had. - Oh, and an other thing. Eng. is my second language. - I get, that questions and answers should be in Eng, but does the editor have to?

Comment: @toLucky This site is an English site so yes, of course the editor and documentation are in English. Note that there are [other language versions of SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285042), although be warned that the editors are the same and the help buttons are in the same places. *"a first-time-writer should know this how?"* -- Can you clarify what you mean by "this"?

Comment: (To me what it is starting to sound like is that you *legitimately* didn't see the help icon [that's *totally fine*, and very important if it's a common issue], but instead of being able to clearly express that or say "whoops, I didn't see that", you're having trouble taking a step back for a moment, accepting what happened as a possible mistake [which is OK] on your part, and thinking about alternatives. Your comments are transitioning into rant-y and somewhat demanding, and your OP has that tone as well. :) )