# Code formatting article in help center is confusing

Tags: discussion, bug, code-formatting, help-center

Prompted by [Does inline code span require HTML escaping?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292972/is-inline-code-span-requires-html-escaping), I took a look at [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). While it's mostly accurate, there is a fair amount of ambiguous terminology and subtle inaccuracies. I've identified at least the following issues, there are likely others:

1. Ambiguous terminology, primarily centered around "code" (the word) vs. "`<code>`" (the HTML tag):

   - "code block" is used to refer to the 4-space indented version.
   - "block of code" is used to refer to a piece of arbitrary text that, semantically, is code (so you could say strange things like "select a block of code then press ctrl-k to turn it into a code block" within the context of that article).
   - "inline code" starts off referring to backticked text, but then is identified as creating an inline "`<code>` span".
   - "code span", in the mean time, appears in the backtick code section, but the description of its behavior matches inline `<code>` tags, not backticks.
2. The *Code Block* section states:

   > Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code>` block:

   But this is not accurate. Indenting four spaces is not the exact equivalent of a `<pre><code>` block. In particular:

   - Indenting strips the first four spaces, but wrapping in `<pre><code>` does not.
   - HTML entities need not be escaped when indenting four spaces, but must be escaped in `<pre><code>` text.

   **Conclusion**: That section correctly describes the behavior of indenting four spaces, but incorrectly associates it with `<pre><code>`. The quoted sentence above should probably be changed to "To format a block of code, indent the code by four spaces." and not mention `<pre>` or `<code>` at all.
3. The *Inline Code* section suffers from a similar issue:

   > Use backticks (in the upper left corner of most keyboards) to create an inline `<code>` span:

   As with the above, this is not accurate. Backticks are not equivalent to `<code>`, in particular:

   - HTML entities need not be escaped in backticks, but must be escaped in `<code>` text.

   **Conclusion:** That section incorrectly associates backticks with `<code>`. The quoted sentence above should probably be changed to "To insert inline code, enclose the code in backticks (in the upper left corner of most keyboards)." and not mention `<code>` at all.
4. The *Inline Code* section starts off talking about backticks, but then suddenly changes to describing the behavior of `<code>`, which is different. In particular:

   > Note that, unlike code blocks, code spans require you to manually escape any HTML within them.

   While this may make sense on its own (assuming you interpret "code spans" as "`<code>` spans"), in the context of that section it does not make sense. It is describing a different feature than the main topic of that section.

   **Conclusion:** The quoted sentence above should be changed to "As with code blocks, inline code enclosed in backticks does not require you to manually escape any HTML." Basically the opposite of what it says. Mention of "code spans" should be removed, with "inline code" used to consistently refer to backticked text.
5. The phrases "ignored" and "do not work" are used ambiguously in both sections. From *Code Blocks*:

   > Markdown and HTML are ignored within a code block:

   Here, "ignored" could mean HTML is not interpreted at all, thus not requiring HTML to be escaped, or it could mean the HTML itself is ignored, thus unescaped tags are simply stripped silently. Furthermore, it is not clear from context because, as mentioned in point 2 above, this section conflates indented code with `<pre><code>`, and so both interpretations of "ignored" apply depending on what you think this may be describing.

   Similarly, from *Inline Code*:

   > Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them.

   The issue is the same: "Will not work" could mean HTML won't be interpreted (and thus no escaping required) or it could mean HTML will be stripped and will have no effect, and the context is again not helpful because the section ambiguously describes the opposite behavior of backticks vs. `<code>`.

The general solution, I think, is:

- Don't use the phrase "code span" anywhere, for any reason.
- Don't mention `<pre>` or `<code>` at *all*, or at most mention `<pre>`, only, in a separate section on its own (with notes that it's good for plain text rather than code, which can be formatted by indenting). While it's true that they can be used for formatting, it's also the case that nearly everything can be accomplished through Markdown syntax alone.
- In general, don't mix Markdown with HTML in the formatting help. Mention Markdown only. While you can argue that HTML should be included for "completeness", in my opinion this article should be a clear tip-of-the-iceberg that introduces users to formatting and covers 99% of the bases, with more advanced HTML stuff to be found elsewhere. In particular, `<pre>` is sometimes useful, `<code>` is very rarely, if ever, useful, and indenting four spaces or using backticks is *good enough* for most cases. There's no reason to explain the rest here, certainly not at the expense of clarity.
- <s>Link to [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) (if it's not there already, correct me if I'm just missing it).</s> [Probably better not to...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348465/code-formatting-article-in-help-center-is-confusing?noredirect=1#comment468829_348465).

What do you guys think? Any other wording improvements? Can we clear up this article?

Comment: I agree with this article almost entirely, except for the last bullet. That post links to the help center. So if we did that, we'd get an infinite loop. Or maybe just a Moebius strip...

Comment: Note re your penultimate bullet point: `<pre><code>` (the real thing, not the standard four-space-indented blocks) is useful to be able to get syntax-highlighted code blocks that permit Markdown or HTML formatting as well, for e.g. emphasizing or striking out a particular line of code.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan One day, we suddenly notice that all activity on SO has halted, and SE's logs show all users stuck in an infinite loop of /help/formatting and /q/251361 requests. Development of all products everywhere is frozen as developers are trapped in the infinite help center loop, and more are drawn in out of curiosity from media reports. The world's economy collapses. Humanity plunges into an eternal, dystopian, apocalyptic hell. Dolphins and cats evolve into the dominant species. The Thousand Year Dolphin Cat War devastates the planet, rendering life impossible. Oops.

Comment: I'll add that information about `<kbd></kbd>` is also missing.

Comment: The doomsday scenario assumes that anyone actually *reads* this formatting help. I see little evidence of that. Agree 100% on not mentioning HTML anywhere in the Markdown help. That's just confusing and unnecessary. We want people to use Markdown, not HTML.

Comment: @CodyGray: isn't actually reading the help information the way *out* of the loop?

Comment: If it's plain text you can also <!-- language: lang-none -->

Comment: @JasonC: Fortunately, we're protected from that disaster by the fact that *people don't read*, and thus won't go to /help/formatting in the first place... ;-)

Comment: "Humanity plunges into an eternal, dystopian, apocalyptic hell." Have you tried jQuery?