# How to add CSS on Stack Overflow like HTML to be displayed?

Tags: discussion, design, code

I am new to Stack Overflow so probably will make a mistake in the asking area.

I feel so stupid want to ask a question over here: Can I paste my HTML, but cannot paste my CSS? It won't display in the nice grey area, but end up on a plain white background and that makes it not too readable. I have searched here and on YouTube, but I did not find the solutions.

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Have you looked over the [**Editing Help**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? It's linked from the editor when clicking the `?` in the editor when asking a question!

Comment: In addition to Fran's like, there's also [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

When you ask a question it states that if you want to write code press space 4 times or for shortcut use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.