# False positive with code formatting check when using <pre><code>

Tags: support, markdown

(This question is not duplicate of [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), I know how to format code blocks.)

**I want to have some words to be bold in code block.**

To do so I format code block with `<pre><code>`, and bold some text with `<b>`. Preview looks just fine (code is formatted), **but code format check bug/future prevents me to submit answer**.

When I try to post the following code:

```
<pre><code>
public <b>String[]</b> array;
</code></pre>
```

I got this error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: In my opinion all answers that contain "try this" and a code dump should automatically be discarded  anyway.

Comment: It is just for example. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqxey.png) is screenshot of actually answer that I try to write.

Comment: The part you missed is that you need to *"encode HTML entities (like `&lt;` for `<`) yourself"*, when using that method for code formatting.

Comment: @Stijn, I encode all `<` and `>` except `<b>` and `</b>`, because I want to bold some text in code.

Comment: That's not supported.

Comment: @Stijn, why it is not supported? It looks just fine in preview, only thing that prevents me is code format check error/bug/future.

Comment: @Stijn, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvCY2.png) is how it looks in preview.

Comment: That's a bug in the preview then.

Comment: @Stijn, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Qx3.png) is how it looks if i can submit it. Still looks good.

Comment: Did you actually manage to submit that? Or did you fiddle with your browser's developer tools? It's not a matter of looking good or not, it simply isn't supported (afaik).

Comment: @Stijn, I actually submit this on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), where I have enough reputation to skip format check.

Comment: You aren't supposed to format code using `<pre><code>`. You're supposed to indent each line of the block with 4 spaces.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes, almost always i indent each line with 4 spaces. But now i want to bold some text in code, so I use `<pre><code>`

Comment: @Stijn, can you, please, explain, why is it duplicate? There is nothing about format check in question `How do I format my code blocks`

Comment: It is not a false positive. You are trying to post something that consists *entirely* of code. That's not allowed. You should add some explanation to accompany your answer.

Comment: @diraria The thing is that you've run into an unintentional feature. The key point is that formatting (e.g. **bold** or *italic*) in a code block is not supported. The Markdown engine just so happens to support doing it in certain scenarios, as is evident by the preview you linked and by being able to post it as a user with enough reputation, but it is not intentional by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @CodyGray, code in this question is for example, in real answer there are some explanations. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqxey.png) is screenshot of real answer.

Comment: @Stijn, thanks for explanation. I think that your explanations should be the answer to my question, instead of closing this as duplicate.

Comment: OK, I can agree with that. Let's see if we can get this post reopened then.

Comment: Not sure why this question has so many downvotes. It seems like a legitimate and relevant question to me. @cody-gray: I believe you, but the [SO help site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) links to an [overview of allowed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/361134), which includes both `<pre>` and `<code>`. As mentioned by the OP, these tags work as expected in the code preview. That may be a bug (or unintentional feature), as mentioned by @stijn, but I think it's a bit confusing nonetheless. Maybe this restriction could be mentioned explicitly on the help page?

Comment: @Dennis these tags work as expected not only in preview. If user has enough reputation to skip formatting check, [then question will be posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356288/false-positive-with-code-formatting-check-when-using-precode?noredirect=1#comment512390_356288), and absolutely correct answer will be generated (with desired effect — bold text in code). So I think that it is bug/feature of format checking, but my question is heavily downvoted...

Comment: It would be nice to have this as an actual feature, e.g. so we could <s>strike through</s> specific lines of code in a code block. That could really help to highlight specific issues in code blocks, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Dennis actually you can use this feature, to do so just post answer with any content, then edit answer to replace it with actual content. Most likely format check will not be triggered for your edit. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377622/5812238) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into an unintentional feature. The key point is that formatting (e.g. **bold** or *italic*) in a code block is not supported. The Markdown engine just so happens to support doing it in certain scenarios, as is evident by the preview you linked and by being able to post it as a user with enough reputation, but it is not intentional by Stack Exchange.

If you want to highlight certain pieces of a code block, consider inlining them in the explanation of the code.

Comment: Do you happen to know: Is this simply not supported, or is it also actively discouraged?

Comment: @Dennis I don't, sorry. My answer is a guess, the only way to be sure is to have a developer chime in.

Answer (score 4):

Though some users say that it is unintentional feature, **you can still use it**.

### Live demo:

```
Some bold text
Some strike text
```

### How to use

Format your code with `<pre><code>` instead of four spaces, and then just use tags like `<b>` or `<s>`:

```
<pre><code>
Some <b>bold text</b>
Some <s>strike text</s>
</code></pre>
```

### Workaround for users with small reputation

Submit question/answer with any content, **then edit your question/answer**: replace it with actual content (with bold/strike text in code). In my experience, format check will not be triggered for editing.

Note: If you have enough reputation to skip format check, then you don't need to use this workaround.

Comment: In this context, you can also use <kbd>...</kbd> inside code block, but the syntax highlighter breaks it (remember to escape all &lt;)