# Why can't I put the code in the right format?

Tags: support, code-formatting

There are no blank lines in my original code. Why are there so many blank lines after publishing?

[image]

#### My original code

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is more clear to check here.

[Effect on a published webpage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422216/how-to-solve-the-issue-ah00169-caught-sigterm-shutting-down-in-apche)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you probably should've asked this on the [Unix & Linux meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1. you ought to have really asked in relevant site [meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/) 2. when using bullets/numbering, code needs an additional tab(4 spaces). Suggested an [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/229533)

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow (and other SE sites, IIUC), support inline HTML formatting, which is how your `<Directory >` (and other XML tags) are being parsed. Instead, you should format your code by indenting it with four spaces so it's displayed as a code block. E.g.:

```
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You can find additional information in the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You can check my format for the code snippet  on the webpage i provided,four blanks already added ,please check and talk.

Comment: @scrapy as I mentioned 4 _more_ spaces in case of numbering..https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks may help

Comment: I notice that 8 blanks added at the beginning of every line.thank Rao.