# Adding Code Sample functionality seems buggy

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

When asking a question, it's important to add readable code.

So, when wanting to ask a question recently, I clicked the **Code Sample > {}** icon and pasted the formatted code into place, which results in (notice everything other than first line is indented incorrectly):

```
function foo() {
if (this) {
    doThat();
} else if (that) {
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    doNothing();
}
```

}

Whereas if I add the code to the post first, highlight it, then click the **Code Sample > {}** icon, it renders correctly, like this:

```
function foo() {
    if (this) {
        doThat();
    } else if (that) {
        doSomethingElse();
    } else {
        doNothing();
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? Or is the second way I added the code the "right" way?

The code was formatted and indented correctly, I wasn't expecting the Code Sample feature to magically indent it too.

The code was formatted using JSFiddle tidy functionality (4 spaces indented), it's even worse if using 2 spaces to indent.

Comment: That's how it always worked, with the button or the keyboard shortcut. Doc says "select text and press CTRL+K".

Comment: Note that if you're coming from JSFiddle, you can probably use the Stack Snippet functionality. It's the button that has the brackets in a page. It has the same four quadrants to place your HTML,CSS, and JS, and see the result of running it. The ability to add external resources is a little different and frankly needs work, but it can help those people who are blocked from jsfiddle.net...

Answer (score 2):

When you click on <kbd>{}</kbd> without selecting any code, the editor inserts a tab(4 spaces) which is the markdown syntax for adding code. Then it provides a selected text "enter code here".

If your code is multiline, it is pasted on the new line(outside the editor's code area) and doesn't get parsed as code in your post as it won't have the tab. Here your way of indenting code seems to affect your post if it already uses tab for indenting. It is parsed by the editor as part of code block and your actual code will not show indentation.Note: your last `}` doesnt have tab indentation as per code formatting. If you use 2 space indentation the next line is taken as normal text.

```
function foo() {//1st line initial tab because of {} clicked
if (this) { //tab due to formatting parsed as code block and not formatted  inside block
    doThat();
} else if (that) {
    doSomethingElse();
} else {
    doNothing();
}
```

}//no tab as per formatting so not parsed as code.

Preselecting the code snippet and *then* clicking the button <kbd>{}</kbd> gives a tab(4 spaces) to each line in your code block and it will be shown as code in your post. This doesn't look like a bug.

For more in-depth [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I know how it "should" work but what I'm suggesting is that it's not very clear. I've seen quite a few questions where the last `}` in a code block is not indented, and this will be why. When you click without selecting anything there is a clear message saying "enter code here", it doesn't mention single line, no multiline etc etc. If what you say is the way it's "supposed" to work, then I'd suggest maybe disabling the code sample icon unless any text is selected.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney with you there.. it was difficult for me too initially... New users will find it difficult. Learning markdown syntax made things easier. Have edited a lot of new users code now. Disabling button till user selects code will only confuse a new user IMO especially if they have not gone through markdown help section.https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @DarrenSweeney you could create a feature request if you want for disabling the button and see what the rest of SO community has to say...

Comment: I always use ^K instead of the button, so it won't be a problem for me. / The underlying problem is people not reading help, or not even check the preview pane to see if their question is correctly formatted.

Comment: @user202729 the button or keyboard shortcut has the same effect.. and yes users just want to get their question posted by any means necessary.