# How do I format a table in a post?

Tags: support, formatting

Yes I read this:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

But nowhere there (or the links therein) does it explain how to format a representation of a table. If I have 2 columns and 10 rows in a table (or an Excel sheet to paste here) how do I format that to look right in a question?  No matter what I try, it looks like this:

ORG_ID  EndDate
99968042    1/31/2017
99968042    2/14/2017
99968042    2/14/2017
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99899776    1/20/2018
99843366    12/17/2017
99843366    1/4/2018

Comment: You did it, but you didn't tell me how.  I need to know how to do that please

Comment: He formatted it as code (https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You could also try using HTML

Comment: Thanks. Don't know the first thing about HTML. I will try formatting as code and see what happens.

Comment: When you say to format as code, you mean put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line?  As far as the preview shows, that puts every row on a different line, but the columns are mashed together and not "columns" and it doesn't look at all like what jarlh did to my post (which I was really looking for the ANSWER to  my question jarlh, not for you to fix it without explanation).  Not that I can really tell for another 90 minutes.... :(

Comment: well jarlh indeed only formatted your example as code (indented by 4 spaces). I just took a closer look, HTML tables are not allowed. So you are stuck with code-blocks wich contain ASCII-tables.

Comment: You can also use `<pre></pre>` tags instead of spaces.

Comment: @Stijn The question I marked it as doesn't specify any base knowledge. If anything, this question shows more research. The titles look very dupe-y, and you can edit one of the answers in the dupe target to specify you should use code formatting to share the table, if you think that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to format the text as code, as one user demonstrated by editing your original question on SO.

```
ORG_ID  EndDate
99968042    1/31/2017
99968042    2/14/2017
99968042    2/14/2017
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99900699    1/10/2018
99899776    1/20/2018
99843366    12/17/2017
99843366    1/4/2018
```

See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for guidance on code formatting.