# Reference for formatting code

Tags: discussion

A recurring problem with new question-askers is poorly formatted code. When I look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) I do not find any guide to formatting code. Shouldn't there be something really obvious to help with that?

Comment: It's this isn't it? [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: There is [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the Help Center. And when you hit the ["More" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53HpT.png) in the editor you'll be forwarded to [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: It's linked to on the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page which should be getting read in it's entirety anyway

Comment: Reasoning where I would look for something like that, my personal intuition would be the "how do I ask a good question" page. Nada.

Comment: Formatting isn't just important for asking though, @Gimby .

Comment: The reference from @khelwood is great.  But not on SO help. Ivar 's reference is what I was looking for. That fact that I did not see it seems to say that it is poorly placed.

Comment: @Larnu true enough, But at least something. Anything. A hint that the code formatting button exists and should be used, at the least.

Comment: It’s all here: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is in the [model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) section of the Help Centre, labeled [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

It is, however, one of the topics displayed on the help centre's home page:
[image]

Though you might expect to find it in the Asking section, good formatting is important for answers too, and other parts of the site, such as tag info pages. Therefore it's better putting it in a less specific area, and the Model section works well for that.

Comment: Yes,  This does it. Although I must say it is not an intuitive place for that link.  Thanks for poining this out.

Comment: The help center's home page also includes a big search field across the top, and typing "formatting" into that brings up that article as the second hit...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Yes.  I was using that incorrectly. I just scrolled all the way to the top and searched SO instead of searching help only.  Searching SO gives unhelpful results, but I see that if I had used it correctly to search only help, it does give a good answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The page [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) is on this [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) but maybe not easy enough to find if you're starting from the help centre.